# How to accept string starting with # in python?

Tags: python, bash, shell, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am working on a python program where I need to enter a hastag in the terminal in following manner:

```
[delta@localhost Desktop]$ python CheckHastag.py #football
```

after executing it throws out error as 
IndexError: list index out of range

It is because python is not accepting string starting with "#", however I tried without `#` i.e.

```
[delta@localhost Desktop]$ python CheckHastag.py football
```

it works.
So how do I make my program to accept the hashtag i.e string starting
 with # ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The shell treats `#` as the start of a comment, so the Python interpreter never gets to see what comes after the `#`.

This can be easily demonstrated using the `echo` command:

```
$ echo #football

$ echo football
football
```

You have several options for working around this:

```
$ python CheckHastag.py "#football"
$ python CheckHastag.py '#football'
$ python CheckHastag.py \#football
```

Comment: Thank you so much.